# OSError: Python library not found: libpython3.9mu.so.1.0, libpython3.9m.so, etc., when running pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to create an executable from a python script, using pyinstaller, and am getting the error seen in the subject line.  The particulars:

- python - version 3.9.2
- pyinstaller - version 4
- I am running on Debian Linux

I evoke pyinstaller as:

```
pyinstaller --onefile pythonfile.py
```

When I looked to see what `libpython*.so` files were resident, I see `libpython3.7*.so`, and the error shows I need to install `libpython3.9*so` files.

I have tried:

```
 pip3 install PyInstaller (to load on pyinstaller)
 apt-get install python3-dev (as recommended in the pyinstaller error msg)
 apt-get install python-dev (as recommended in the pyinstaller error msg)
 apt-get upgrade
 apt-get update
```

but still get the error.  How can I get the correct `libpython*.so` files loaded (i.e., 3.9)?  TIA.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to generate the shared lib using:

```
env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" pyenv install 3.9.2
```

I'm not sure whether 3.9.2 is working if not try 3.9.0

Official Document [Here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#how-to-build-cpython-with---enable-shared).

Comment: Thanks.  That did create the shared lib, once I got pyenv installed.   I now have an executable.  The only other issue was it could not find the matplotlibrc file.  I put a copy in the dir where I am building, which worked, but I think one can specify its location in the *.spec file - in datas[]?

Answer (score 8):

Or try this:
sudo apt-get install libpython3.7-dev
it worked for me

Comment: or replace '3.7' with any of your relevant python 3.x version - thanks :-)

Comment: Please englobe apt command with code enrichment.